# AndroidTest Manifest permission not detected

Tags: android-manifest, android-permissions, android-testing, android-espresso

I have androidTest Manifest that has this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE" />
```

However, when I run the test, this permission is not set in my devDebug build. It only works when I add it to main/AndroidManifest.xml.

Full androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.test.mobile">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
        tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE" />
</manifest>
```

Error:

```
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.test.mobile has not requested permission android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE
```

I don't want to add this permission in main Manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a debug folder and add AndroidManifest.xml in it with the permission.

Comment: Sorry, create the bug folder where?

Comment: @JoeMaher at app/src/devDebug/AndroidManifest.xml
Note: "dev" is my productFlavor and "Debug" is the buildType