# androidTest AndroidManifest.xml ignored

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-testing

I have the same issue mentioned in this post [AndroidTest Manifest permission not detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283294/androidtest-manifest-permission-not-detected)

and this post [AndroidManifest in androidTest directory being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244998/androidmanifest-in-androidtest-directory-being-ignored)

--> If I put the test manifest in `androidTest`, `debugAndroidTest`, `androidTestDebug`, it never gets picked up and merged.

the answers about putting the AndroidManifest.xml in the `debug` folder are correct; that does seem to work. (put the test manifest in `src/debug`

What I want to know is why can't you put it in the `androidTest` directory? All the documentation I've read while trying to figure this out makes it sound like you should be able to, and that if you can't then I'm thinking that sounds like some bug in the manifest merger.

For what it's worth, I'm using Android Studio

Comment: Saying "I have the same issue" makes this NOT any less of a duplicate, **see:** [AndroidManifest in androidTest directory being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244998/androidmanifest-in-androidtest-directory-being-ignored)

Answer (score 5):

That is correct and totally agree with you on the confusing documentation. The `AndroidManifest.xml` under `androidTest*` source sets would be packaged for the instrumentation APK that does your tests on your actual app APK. If you open the generated APKs for `debug` and `androidTest` under `build/outputs/apk/` after compiling your app module with the command `gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest` (assuming that you haven't changed the `testBuildType` in you `build.gradle`, more info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html#change-the-test-build-type)), you'll find that any `AndroidManifest.xml` configuration added under `androidTest` will be in the `androidTest` APK and not in your `debug` app APK.

And also as you said, in case you need test specific configurations like extra permissions, you'll have to place them in the  `AndroidManifest.xml` under the `debug` source set instead of `main`, hence they'll only be available for testing your app but not in your release build. Of course you can always double check by opening the generated APKs after compiling to make sure that the configuration is right for each build variant.

Comment: @josh has this answer helped you?

Answer (score -2):

If you need to add extra permissions for tests, you can do it.

You should set the same `android:sharedUserId` in default `AndroidManifest.xml` and `androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml`.

For example:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:sharedUserId="com.yourpackagename.uid">

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:sharedUserId="com.yourpackagename.uid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.***" />

</manifest>
```

For details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14196493/3901000

Comment: This is not the way to go because of security reasons. You will end up with the sharedUserId flag set in your release product.

Comment: @Juke sharedUserId can be set only for debug build in debug/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Where did you get this information? The documentation mentions nothing about the flag being limited to debug builds. In fact it explicitly mentions that the certificate of the apps has to be identical. This mechanism should protect from access by e.g. an hijacked app. Though i would recommend using sharedUserId  only if really needed.

Comment: @Juke to set this flag only for debug builds you should put it in debug/AndroidManifest.xml as I mentioned earlier. Then it will not be shipped to production. This flag can be useful for example for ui tests permissions, if you want to add permissions only when instrumentation apk is installed.